# Interfacing LPC1343 with Compact Flash

Tags: cortex-m3

I am interfacing Compact Flash with [LPC1343](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1311_13_42_43.pdf). Which is better- 16 bit data and 3 bit addressing or 8 bit data and 8 bit addressing? Anyone please suggest.

Comment: 8 bit data and registered addressing.

Comment: You mean 8 bit data & 8 bit addressing...

Comment: Which is better depends on your (unstated) goals.  Do you want a minimal circuit?  Maximum performance?  Can you spare the pins for 16 bit mode?

Comment: I am using 8 address line & 8 data line. In PC card IO mode I've interfaced IORD & IOWR with GPIO pins. Further if OE signal is required (for reading CIS & configuration registers) then which pin it should be interfaced with?

Comment: Can I use 3 bit address along with CE to access all 8 bit data in PC card IO mode?